# How to display data in gridview when on click event in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

here is cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_logdetails", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        }
```

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Book_id" EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White"  Height="240px" 
        Width="755px" BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="2px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Book_id" >
            <ControlStyle BorderColor="Red" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="bookid" HeaderText="bookid" SortExpression="bookid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="studentid" HeaderText="studentid" SortExpression="studentid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="returndate" HeaderText="returndate" SortExpression="returndate" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="returnstatus" HeaderText="returnstatus" SortExpression="returnstatus" />

            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the [**screenshot**](http://s21.postimg.org/ri0m4w61z/untitled.jpg) of my executed query

I'm new to .net, can anyone guide me to display data in gridview by calling storedprocedure.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried calling the stored procedure, reading the results, and actually assigning the results as the datasource to your GridView from a click event? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know, how to do that? i'm new to .net

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_logdetails", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid",1);
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource=ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You need to pass `@bookid` parameter to SP. I have hard coded the value of `@bookid` to 1 but you need to pass this as `parameter`.

Comment: it shows error like this Procedure or function 'sp_logdetails' expects parameter '@bookid', which was not supplied.

Comment: Also if your SP expects other parameters also pass those parameters.

Comment: I can't understand.. what is 1? what should i replace to 1

Comment: You need to pass bookid on basis of which SP will search record from DB.

Comment: i need to know (@bookid,?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99776/discussion-between-rani-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Comment: Back now was out for lunch.